# MongoDB Aggregation, tabular typ results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document model that looks like this

```
{
    _id: objectId,
    per: [{
        _pid: objectId,
        thing1: sting,
        thing2: string
    }],
    ore: [{
        _oid: objectId,
        thing1: sting,
        thing2: string
    }],
    tre: [{
        _tid: objectId,
        thing1: sting,
        thing2: string
    }]
}
```

and I want to pull back a tabular representation

```
[
    {_id,_pid,thing1,thing2},
    {_id,_pid,thing1,thing2},
    {_id,_oid,thing1,thing2},
    {_id,_oid,thing1,thing2},
    {_id,_oid,thing1,thing2},
    {_id,_tid,thing1,thing2}
]
```

How would I go about doing this - Im sure it's an aggregation thing

Comment: What you want is not a valid JSON, could you modify that, just to make it clear what's the expected result ?

Comment: Mongo query will always return the result in JSON format. Can you represent your tabular data in JSON form? Maybe you are looking for export as CSV. Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: done- i meant for an array of objects to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) within aggregation would let you combine multiple arrays into one:

See live at [**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-NtjUgblZva)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
     _id: "$_id",
     array: { $push: {
          $setUnion: [
            "$per",
            "$ore",
            "$tre"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

From that point, it just unwinding the result to your liking.

Here is the completed example with all the unwinding: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z9-HHMoQOPA

Comment: the double unwind was helpful in the playground

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      array: {
        $push: {
          $setUnion: [
            "$per",
            "$ore",
            "$tre"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$array"
  }
])

Comment: can you tell me how I would (1) combine the _id into the grouped array - so it shows with EACH object - not the _id,array like now and (2) to specify the fields in the grouped array to 'project' - if i wanted to specify or leave out some fields....
much appreciated

Comment: Here is the new mongoplayground with $project and $repaceRoot stages: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z9-HHMoQOPA let me know if it works for you and I'll update the answer